# Syncing SQL server data across different SQL server instances

Tags: .net, sql-server, git

Windows Application using Microsoft SQL server express edition.

My application can be used in multiple branches of the client. As the primary requirement was the software should work offline application has separate database server at each client location.

Now my client wants that data to be synced across all the branches on a regular interval.

So I am thinking of following ways

1. central database server which will get updated data from multiple branches (but client don't want to invest in sql server hosting)
2. As each branch will modify data that belongs to that particular branch only (data identified by branch id column in all the tables), Each branch will have main copy of its own. Now if I generate a XML for all the tables having data of that particular branch and send it to central webserver and the other branches will fetch data from central server. but the problem is as the data size increases it will require unnecessary upload and download of duplicate data.
3. Storing the xml generated in a local git repo at each branch. branches will generate new xml only for itself. Now, this data will be pushed to central git repository from where other branches will pull the data.

I am really sorry if this doesn't make any sense

Could you please suggest if you have a better approach for this